# How do I push a webView from a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to put push three different webViews from a View Controller with three buttons in it using a Navigation Controller. Here's the view controller with the buttons' header:

```
@interface SocialButtons : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *twitterButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *linkedInButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *youTubeButton;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *twitterButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *linkedInButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *youTubeButton;

-(IBAction)pushTwitter:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)pushLinkedIn:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)pushYouTube:(id)sender;

@end
```

I'm trying to use the actions to push a webView Controllers, but I'm getting no reaction when the button is pressed. I have it set up to commit to the pushTwitter action upon being touched up inside. the action is defined as:

```
-(IBAction)pushTwitter:(id)sender {

    Dg3_z_Z4_8AppDelegate *AppDelegate = (Dg3_z_Z4_8AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication     sharedApplication] delegate];

    TwitterWebView *wvController = [[TwitterWebView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterWebView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [AppDelegate.socNavControl pushViewController:wvController animated:YES];

    }
```

Then the web view (entitled TwitterWebView) is supposed to load, but it fails to even push to the next view. I have a feeling the issue is in the code above. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Set a breakpoint to make sure it gets into pushTwitter:

Comment: It gets there. That's where it fails.

Comment: Do you have any ideas other than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)pushTwitter:(id)sender {


    TwitterWebView *wvController = [[TwitterWebView alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterWebView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:wvController animated:YES];

}
```

If you are not using ARC you are missing a release statement here. Is socNavControl a UINavigationController or a subclass of it? Please provide some more code. It is hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Sorry about that. SocNavControl is a UINavigationController that is in my App Delegate.That worked though. Thanks!